# Построение двух диаграмм на одном графике

Tags: python, matplotlib

Доброго времени суток!

Есть два массива gmm.score_samples. Необходимо построить их диаграммы на одном графике.
Первый график:

```
gmm = mixture.GaussianMixture(n_components = 500, covariance_type='diag').fit(dfle)
dfleg = gmm.score_samples(dfle)
print ('Score for source seq = ', dfleg)
plt.hist(dfleg, bins = 100)
```

Второй график:

```
gmmr = mixture.GaussianMixture(n_components = 500).fit(dfler)
dflegr = gmmr.score_samples(dfler)
print ('Score for random seq =',dflegr)
plt.hist(dflegr, bins = 'auto')
```

На вход всего этого дела подается DataFrame из excel-файла на 25000 строк.

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Вариант 1.

```
pyplot.hist(x, bins, alpha=0.5, label='x')
pyplot.hist(y, bins, alpha=0.5, label='y')
pyplot.show()
```

Вариант 2.

```
pyplot.hist([x, y], bins, label=['x', 'y'])
pyplot.show()
```